# What is the ethical way of writing co-author names?

Tags: publications, authorship

I want to know how much a contribution a person should have to be the co-author, ethically in computer science and engineering field.

1. If a person help you to collect some amount of data (not all), either giving you permission or  participated himself to help you in data collection
2. Proofread the paper once or twice
3. Supervised you or co-supervised you but did not work in paper writing nor reviewing because of time constraints
4. The head of departments or labs
5. The one who supports you financially.

So I want to know, whom you will consider the co-author and whom not in the above list. What should the order of authorship in above scenario?

Comment: Order of authors (and also who should be one) also depends on the field (which you should mention).

Comment: "Proofreading" is ambiguous. It might depend on whether it is just for the use of language or on the content itself. And note that the standard for this varies by field. Math is quite different from high energy physics, for example.

Comment: @Buffy its first time I cam to know it varies with the field, my question is particularly related to engineering and computer science.  Proofreading means the use of language like grammatical mistakes

Comment: Note this answer: https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/150704/75368

Comment: i think my queries are somehow different. i mean should I add other authors name in reference to points I made

Comment: Please ask only one question. This is at least five questions, most of which are duplicates.  https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/535/what-does-author-order-indicate https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/73480/is-someone-who-solely-contributes-negative-feedback-to-a-paper-considered-an-aut https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/19362/is-it-ethical-for-advisors-to-automatically-coauthor-papers https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/127439/author-order-seniority-vs-contribution?r=SearchResults&s=3|60.1604 etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might have to check with your journal guidelines. Here are some examples:

[**Elsevier**](https://www.elsevier.com/__data/assets/pdf_file/0006/653883/Authorship-factsheet-March-2019.pdf)

> Four criteria must all be met to be credited
> as an author:
>
> - Substantial contribution to the study
>   conception and design, data acquisition,
>   analysis, and interpretation.
> - Drafting or revising the article for
>   intellectual content.
> - Approval of the final version.
> - Agreement to be accountable for all
>   aspects of the work related to the
>   accuracy or integrity of any part of
>   the work.
>
> [...]
>
> Three types of authorship are considered
> unacceptable:
>
> - ‘Ghost’ authors, who contribute
>   substantially but are not acknowledged
>   (often paid by commercial sponsors);
> - ‘Guest’ authors, who make no
>   discernible contributions, but are
>   listed to help increase the chances of
>   publication;
> - ‘Gift’ authors, whose contribution is
>   based solely on a tenuous affiliation with
>   a study.

[**Springer**](https://www.springer.com/gp/editorial-policies/authorship-principles)

Has nearly the same principles.

**Your university**

Likely your university has a document where they spell out the guidelines. The ethics department, if it exists, shall answer all of your questions.

**Your specific questions** (my opinion)

1. If a person help you to collect some amount of data (not all), either giving you permission or participated himself to help you in data collection - *Yes (although I'm not sure what you mean by the "giving you permission" part)*
2. Proofread the paper once or twice - *I'd say no. Correcting typos is not a major scientific contribution.*
3. Supervised you or co-supervised you but did not work in paper writing nor reviewing because of time constraints - *If supervised means giving guidance and participating in discussions, yes. If supervised means just overlooking the progress of the paper without substantial input, then no.*
4. The head of departments or labs - *Just being the head of lab does not suffice. The authors contribute to the project directly.*
5. The one[s] who support you financially. - *These are typically credited in the acknowledgment section, not by giving them authorship.*

Acknowledgments, on the other hand, are less strict. So even minor contributions, conversations or comments on the draft might be sufficient for putting someone in the acknowledgments.

---

Note: In this answer I'm not saying anything about the order of the authors because it's field dependent and I have no experience about it (my field being one that adopts alphabetical order).